# install CUPS in windows

Tags: odoo, printers, cups

in order to install `base_report_to_printer` module I realized that I should install `cups` as it is an external_dependencies

```html
    'external_dependencies': {
        'python': ['cups'],
    },
```

It's okey to install it on ubuntu by running `pip install pycups` but how can I install it on windows ?

Comment: This thread might help you on how to install pip on windows, and hence continue installing your dependencies in a familiar fashion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows

Comment: I have already installed `pip`, but when I launch the command `pip install pycups`  loadx errors are here `Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pycups ... error`

Comment: even `wheel`  is here because when I launch `pip install wheel` ==> `Requirement already satisfied: wheel in c:\python27\lib\site-packages`

Comment: @Borealis What did you do instead of installing CUPS in windows ? I too have a similar issue.
I am not able to take prints from local machine (windows and ubuntu) when my odoo is installed in a server.

Comment: With windows install the python that ODOO uses is in the ODOO install folder in my case "c:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\python". If you run PIP it needs to be from this folder. in that folder I am running "python  -m pip install pycups"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. From [cups.org](https://www.cups.org/)

> CUPS is the standards-based, open source printing system developed by Apple Inc. for **macOS®** and other **UNIX®-like** operating systems.

Comment: I am facing the same issue and for this to work on Linux I needed to install the Cups Client aka pycups. The actual CUPS server will need to run on Linux but the client that interacts with it does not need to. My current issue is that I can't build the pycups package in Win10 because VSC++ is not working for me.